# Failed to convert multilinestring to linestring

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I tried to convert some multilinestring data into linestring using:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(
ST_LineMerge(
    ST_SnapToGrid(
        ST_GeomFromText(the_geom),
        0.001)
    )
);
```

and

```
ST_AsText(ST_LineMerge(
ST_GeomFromText(the_geom)
)
)
```

function, but when executing a database some data showing the same multistring values
below is one of them:

```
"MULTILINESTRING((76.4505052014918 29.3605577579601,76.4506218636754 29.3607478108812,76.4511480538787 29.3613277796464,76.4518103152086 29.3620711781354,76.4527672628892 29.3631772485864,76.4531572408356 29.3635752267738,76.4539256694916 29.364440449285,76.4547439604311 29.365369956029,76.4550240785647 29.3656618043844,76.4552426759001 29.3658855962542,76.4555650340103 29.3662556751861,76.4556087620657 29.3663556730666,76.455767298346 29.3668617755123,76.4557673174369 29.3669897943356,76.4558918607226 29.3675826328776,76.4560706995576 29.368422784851,76.4562862936152 29.3694406538537,76.4566033421227 29.3709822940838,76.4568395123292 29.372037249194,76.4570259582372 29.3729957081483,76.4571197426559 29.3734350731336,76.4572698354037 29.3739352007255,76.4573190500858 29.3741392890071,76.4573682490733 29.3742469314174,76.457344669698 29.3743867963434),(76.4573092877099 29.3746523684764,76.4572972911226 29.3747446298991,76.4571720791717 29.3751492332069,76.4570081738852 29.3753587826844,76.4567056895133 29.3756411728579,76.4564101418548 29.3757981626948,76.4561806358876 29.3758648580016,76.4559546435516 29.3759683021827,76.4558235061862 29.3760683197683,76.4552352631393 29.3766506122008,76.4546155360981 29.377308054817,76.4537679226558 29.378150072491,76.4537570213123 29.3782127134124))"

"MULTILINESTRING((80.8962792489216 26.8237892138329,80.8962792489216 26.8237892138329,80.8960534536316 26.8238581478127,80.8959042776709 26.8238877309904),(80.8959404040242 26.823976632038,80.8960326566971 26.8239310587069,80.8962703359495 26.8238515195471,80.896404030529 26.8238037960245,80.896404030529 26.8238037960245))"
```

Above there are two examples. How to convert those values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't merge those geometries into one linestring and you know why when you have a look at them. OpenJUMP has an easy-to-use "Add features from WKT" tool which suits perfectly for this kind of debugging.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

OpenJUMP has a `Convert selected geometries/layers` function that does exactly that.

Question is if that is the intended result. See the example below:

[image: pic1]
[image: pic2]
[image: pic3]